# while installing centos error is that 'sda must have gpt label'

Tags: centos, partition, system-installation, gpt

While trying to install CentOS 6.4 IN DUAL BOOT with win 7 there was this error "sda must have gpt label". I don't know how to fix it and I also don't want to repartition my hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Disable UEFI in BIOS ([manual](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/UEFI_Secure_Boot_Guide/ch02s02.html)) or create a GPT partiition table (`gparted` or `gdisk`).

Example of creating one from [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table):

`# gdisk /dev/sdX
o  # create new empty GUID partition table
n  # partition 1 [enter], from beginning [enter], to 100GiB [+100GiB], linux fs type [enter]
n  # partition 2 [enter], from beginning [enter], to 108GiB [+8GiB],   linux swap    [8200]
w  # write table to disk and exit`

Another option is to use `parted` utility during installation. Inject "CTRL+ALT+F2" during your installation process to go on command line with 'parted' utility.

`parted`
(parted) `print /dev/sda`
(parted) `select /dev/sda`
(parted) `mklabel gpt`
(parted) `yes`
(parted) `print /dev/sda`
(parted) `quit`

then return to installation process with CTRL+ALT+F1.

Comment: My pc is 3 years old.there is no options for UEFI in BIOS setup.

Comment: You'll have to reinstall system and add a gpt label to partition. This will remove all data on partition. I added steps to do during installation to answer.